# C# extending a class in MVVM design pattern (WPF)

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a View that contains a GridView object and a ViewModel that the View represents. Now, I'd like to override the controls in that ViewModel so that I keep the same GUI but with different business logic (i.e. contained within the ViewModel). What's the proper way of doing that?

I'd assume it is not as simple as extending the ViewModel since there's the issue with its GUI being represented in the View (which has a XAML component).

Any thoughts?

Thanks.

Edit: Fixed typo

Comment: Controls in ViewModel? That's something wrong with that. Clarify your question.

Comment: Your question is incomprehensible

Comment: Sorry, I made a few typos. That's fixed. Also, MVVM is almost the same as MVC. So View Model is often viewed as a direct 1-1 mapping to Controller.

Answer (score 0):

What I tend to do, is create a Base ViewModel Class with the standard UI and Control logic in it.

I then set whichever Functions / Subs I want to control individually to overrideable. But I populate them up with default code, such as The standard Form State (Editting/Adding/Deleting) code. Any I want to force to be Overridden are set to Must Override of course.

Then, I create a Individual View-Based ViewModel, inherit from the Base ViewModel Class, override the methods I require, and set this Individual ViewModel to be the DataContext for the View.

You can switch in which ever ViewModels you like using this method, so long as they all inherit from your base ViewModel class.

I hope this helps!